# What is the Cassandra behavior on wrong access?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I would like to know the Cassandra behavior on following activity.

***Step 1#*** Create `customer` role as ***NOSUPERUSER*** using Super user.

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS customer WITH PASSWORD 'Test27' NOSUPERUSER;
```

***Step 2#*** Create the table `emp` in `test` keyspace using super user.

```
CREATE TABLE test.emp (id INT PRIMARY KEY, emp_name TEXT );
```

***Step 3#*** For the moment `customer` role not having permission on `test.emp` table.

```
LIST ALL PERMISSIONS OF customer;
// empty result
```

***Step 4#*** Do `SELECT` query on `test.emp` table using `customer` role.

```
SELECT * FROM test.emp;
// error: no permission for the role.
```

***Step 5#*** then, give `SELECT` permission to customer user using super user role.

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test.example TO customer;
```

***Step 6#*** try `Step 4` again, getting same error.

So internally Cassandra locking the query access or what happening ?

Comment: Maybe the permission did not replicate yet to all nodes? Try to grant select with consistency all.

Comment: i can't find the way to grand with all consistency ? refer: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlGrant.html , how can i do that ?

Comment: just write consistency all; and hit enter in the cqlsh, from then all the queries will be with consistency all. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html

Comment: After Step5, can you do the list permission and show output? Then do current Step6 “select” and let us know the output. Also what is the topology and replication factor on system_auth keyspace? Better if you give the desc keyspace output on it. Also consistency is ALL by default during user creations, so setting explicitly doesn’t have any effect on this command

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the permissions were cached the first time you accessed the table.  Once the authorization cache expires for that users entry it may work.  You can force this by restarting the server or using JMX to drop the authorization cache.

Comment: Any other possibility to reset cache without restart. Because don't want API to down time. Permission enable is one of API service. So frequent grade permission execute as part of API call. Before that, user chances try to execute .

Comment: Checkout the org.apache.cassandra.auth hierarchy in jconsole.  There is an mbean for each cache and you can use the invalidation operation to drop them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JMX to refresh Role / Permission cache. MBean name and operation to invalidate cache below :

```
MBean org.apache.cassandra.auth:type=RolesCache
MBean org.apache.cassandra.auth:type=PermissionsCache

Invoke Operation : invalidate
```

Also there is yaml configuration to update cache in background :

```
permissions_validity_in_ms
roles_validity_in_ms
permissions_update_interval_in_ms
```

Default value of yaml config is 2 sec. If cache is the problem, try setting yaml configuration appropriately.